# Проблема с подменю

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Есть вот такое выпадающее меню, которое нужно реализовать с помощью "указателей-треугольников". Эти указатели сделаны с помощью псевдоэлементов `:before` и `:after`, которые применяются к каждому блоку подменю (всего 3 блока подменю).

Существует следующая проблема:

1. Навожу мышкой на "каталог товаров".
2. Выпадает подменю 1-го уровня ("мебель для спальни" и т.д. - см. картинку).
3. Чтобы перейти мышкой на это подменю, мне нужно двигать ее через указатель-треугольник.
4. если двигать курсор не через указатель, а через пространство между "каталогом" и подменю, то подменю исчезает.

Есть ли решение проблемы, при котором наведя курсор на "каталог товаров" и двигая мышь вниз не через треугольный указатель, подменю не исчезнет?

[image: dropdown menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь единственный верный вариант - задержка исчезновения. Никаких перекрытий быть не должно. Ещё можно загнаться и как на Амазоне вычислять треугольную область в которой скрытия не происходит, но это явно не вариант в данном случае. :)

Comment: У вопроса нет метки js ;)

Answer (score 0):

Есть. Вот несколько вариантов:

1. Показывать элемент в обёртке, которая касается предыдущего меню - при этом hover будет сохраняться.
2. Использовать задержку исчезновения (например, через анимацию). Тут может оказаться проблемой, что анимации не работают со свойством display.
3. Использовать ещё один псевдоэлемент для покрытия участка между двумя меню прозрачным слоем для сохранения hover.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Если использовать еще один псевдоэлемент, то к чему его нужно прикручивать? Ведь более одного псеводэлемента before к под-меню присоединить нельзя. Я попробовал подключить к ссылке "Каталог", но псевдоэлемент даже не отобразился.

Comment: @evgeniyL, можно увидеть пример на jsfiddle или сниппеитом в вопросе?

Comment: Я решил проблему, благодаря второму пункту из вашего списка (с visibility и opacity) и благодаря товарищу выше :). Все-таки иногда лучше не создавать себе дополнительных трудностей на ровном месте. Спасибо.